# Write group names along with labels tikz horizontal bargraph

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I have a horizontal bar-graph as shown in the below picture. I need to group the bars into 3 as shown in the figure i.e. I want to put that flower bracket and write "Group1/Group2/Group3" as shown in the figure.
How can I do this? Also, is it possible to draw a dotted horizontal line between the groups?

Currently, I'm using TikZ pgf-plot for this, but I'm okay with using any other alternatives as well

[image: Bar Graph]

Sample code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=10cm,
        height=10cm,
        enlargelimits=false,
        xbar=0pt,
        xmin=0.0,
        xmax=1.0,
        ymin=0.5,
        ymax=17.5,
        bar width=0.4,
        ytick={17,16,\ldots,1},
        yticklabels={MSE,SSIM,VGG-19 MSE,VGG-19 cosine similarity,ST-MAD,VMAF, ,BRISQUE,NIQE,Inception Score (conditional),Video BLIINDS, Li \etal, , SSA Baseline, Our Model - VGG-19, Our Model - Inception-v3, OurModel - ResNet-50},
        yticklabel style={text height=1ex},
        xlabel=Median SROCC (with std dev),
    ]
        \addplot+[error bars/.cd,
        x dir=both,x explicit]
        coordinates {
            (0.4044,17) +- (0.11, 0.0)
            (0.5274,16) +- (0.09, 0.0)
            (0.5364,15) +- (0.08, 0.0)
            (0.6404,14) +- (0.08, 0.0)
            (0.3730,13) +- (0.12, 0.0)
            (0.6003,12) +- (0.09, 0.0)
            (0.0905,10) +- (0.11, 0.0)
            (0.0819,9) +- (0.12, 0.0)
            (0.0828,8) +- (0.11, 0.0)
            (0.4072,7) +- (0.10, 0.0)
            (0.6371,6) +- (0.09, 0.0)
            (0.7188,4) +- (0.06, 0.0)
            (0.7418,3) +- (0.06, 0.0)
            (0.7922,2) +- (0.06, 0.0)
            (0.8304,1) +- (0.04, 0.0)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```